# How do I remove unneeded spaces found in URLs in Notepad++ using RegEx?

Tags: regex, notepad++

**Source:**

```
<tag>href=" / support/answer/123456 </tag>
```

**Wanted result:**

```
<tag>href="/support/answer/123456</tag>
```

All the partial URLs in question start with `href`, so I've matched
them by searching for `(href[^\<]*)`

How do I replicate the found strings in the Replace field while excluding all spaces?

Comment: Are those string on the tags incomplete? Or it can be complete? I mean the href without the final double quotes.

Comment: Yes, interestingly the strings do not have closing double quotes. I believe this isn't standard HTML, but read by a custom parser.

Answer (score 0):

regex

```
s{ ?[/><] ?}{}g;
```

`\s` to match space incluing new line
`{}` empty bracket to replace empty content
`g` is to do globally

Comment: I think this will remove newlines in the source file if a line begins with a `<`. Also, it seems to remove a lot more than just the spaces. [Check here](http://regex101.com/r/lD1wC7/15)

Comment: Better, you might also want to add the `href[^\<]*`, otherwise it replace delete spaces on many different lines where OP doesn't want that to happen

Answer (score 0):

I found one answer that worked for me now. It captures everything except the spaces into capture groups.

Find:
`(<tag>href.*?) (\/) (.*?) (.*?>)`

Replace:
`$1$2$3$4`

RegEx101:
http://regex101.com/r/lD1wC7/20